# Different Table View Content Insets for Table Header View and Section Headers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITableView with several sections. I am trying to add a view to the table header view, and I want this view to be hidden by default. I accomplish this with this line of code:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -headerView.frame.size.height, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

I also want this to be hidden when the user scrolls to the top, unless the user intentionally scroll a bit higher to see it (kind of like the behavior of a search bar). I do that with this function:

```
  func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let offset = controller.tableView.contentOffset

    let barHeight = controller.headerView.frame.size.height
    if (offset.y < barHeight / 2.0 ) {
      controller.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
    else {
      controller.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-barHeight, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    controller.tableView.contentOffset = offset
  }
```

The problem here is that when I scroll down and my inset is `-barHeight`, the section headers of my table view also use that content inset. Meaning that they disappear behind the navigation bar instead of sticking underneath it like normal.

My question is, how can achieve this "hidden" table header view while also maintaining the sticky section headers in the simplest way possible?

Thanks in advance!